# How to check image quality/resolution/dpi/ppi in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-size

I am using node Js image-size module. I can get height and width of Uploaded image but i need to get resolution (Dpi or PPi ) of image.. So is it possible to get the dpi or ppi in image-size module or i need to use another module.. if yes can anyone tell me the module name.I need to give error messge when upolading image  dpi is less than 87pixel.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: DPI metadata in an image is usually nonsense. What problem are you trying to solve by restricting it?